# Heroku Internal server Error logs ImportError: No module named captcha

Tags: django, heroku, simplecaptcha

## Heroku Internal Server Error with django-simple-captcha

I installed django simple captcha using

```
> pip install django-simple-captcha
```

and made all the necessary changes in settings.py to get captcha running on my local machine. It was working absolutely fine on my machine But when I deployed it on heroku using:

```
> git push heroku master
> 
> heroku pg:reset
> 
> PGUSER=my_username PGPASSWORD=my_password heroku pg:push local_db HEROKU_DB_NAME --app my_appname
```

I got Internal Server Error
on looking at the logs using:

```
heroku logs show :
2013-12-30T18:40:53.136610+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(name)
2013-12-30T18:40:53.136610+00:00 app[web.1]: **ImportError: No module named captcha**
2013-12-30T18:40:53.136610+00:00 app[web.1]:     app = import_module(appname)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify `django-simple-captcha` module requirement in `requirements.txt` file, which should be in your projects root directory.

You can generate `requirements.txt` file using `pip freeze` command as stated in [Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#specify-dependencies-with-pip):

```
$ pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Comment: I tried pip freeze > requirements.txt but it contains only
argparse==1.2.1
gunicorn==18.0
wsgiref==0.1.2